# Reading dates from a csv file giving wrong date

Tags: matlab, csv, date

I have a csv file with a column of dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM.  The first entry has '28/06/2017 17:10'.  Excel for some reason displays this as 28/06/2017  5:10:00 PM.  I want to read this column in matlab and output it in the format dd-mmmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS.  I get a strange date for the ouptut in each column, with the first entry being: '12-August-0033 17:10:00', but the time is fine.

The dates begin in column 2, row 2 of my csv file.

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('winter_cruise_2017_10min_avg.csv');
formatIn = 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM';
A = datestr(raw(2:end,2),formatIn);
formatOut = 'dd-mmmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS';
B = datestr(A,formatOut);
```

Comment: could you post a sample excell file?

Comment: Why would you use `xlsread` on a non-Excel file? For `.csv` you have `csvread`, `dlmread`, `importdata` as well as other functions.

Comment: I wasn't aware of those other functions but thanks, all a learning process.  Not everyone is an expert you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `winter_cruise_2017_10min_avg.csv` containing:

```
28/06/2017 17:10,
```

You can use [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) to interpret it correctly:

```
%% Load data
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('winter_cruise_2017_10min_avg.csv');

%% Interpret text:
formatIn = 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'; % Corrected!
A = datetime(raw, 'InputFormat', formatIn);
%{
A = 
  datetime
   28-Jun-2017 17:10:00
%}

%% Reformat datetime
formatOut = 'dd-mmmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS';
B = datestr(A,formatOut);
%{
B =
    '28-June-2017 17:10:00'
%}
```

Comment: OK, great thank you.  That's what I eventually did in the end.